# Переопределение asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо переделать систему авторизации, чтобы она работа с данными из моей *БД*.

Проект *Asp.net mvc 5, ms sql server*.

Проект разбит на 3 части: `DAL<->BLL<->WebUI`.

Передача объектов `DAL<->BLL` — через *AutoMapper* `<КлассМодели> <-> <DTO>`

`DAL<->BLL` — через *AutoMapper* `<DTO> <-> <ViewModel>`.

Как правильно сделать авторизацию, чтобы работала с моей *БД*?